# how to position a text just direct behind the img

Tags: html, css

well , i got this code

```
echo  '<div class="incoming_msg_img"><img src="https://ptetutorials.com/images/user-profile.png" alt="sunil">'  . $row["Sender"] .  '</img></div>';
```

but the value comes under the img , i want to put it behind the img , any suggestions
example : Image is here
Text is here 
I want Image here => Text here

Comment: This is a CSS/HTML question, not PHP. The description is not clear to me. You want text next to an image, or text split between an image, or text in the middle of 2 images?

Comment: *example : Image is here Text is here I want Image here => Text here*

Comment: Yes, I read that in the question, it didn't help. You have `image here` twice and `text` here twice. So you want the image displayed twice and the same text twice? You also have `=>`, what does that mean in a non programming terms?

Comment: Image element is a self closing tag (Must have a start tag and must not have an end tag.) like so <img src="picture.png" alt="Frog"/> and not <img></img> as you are using it.

Comment: @ user3783243 do i speak chinese ? i wrote IMAGE HERE AND A  TEXT HERE 
Where can't you understand

Comment: @dbf35385ff Calm down. Use MS paint or your choice of image editor to show us what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Simply place the $row var before the  tag. You could also use CSS as was previously described. By using ::after.

```
echo '< div class="incoming_msg_img"> ' . $row['sender'] . '< br/> < img 
src="https://ptetutorials.com/images/user-profile.png" alt="sunil"> </div> ';
```

Better yet

```
 echo '< div class="incoming_msg_img"> ' . $row['sender'] .</div>
```

CSS

```
.incoming_msg_img::after{
   content: url(https://ptetutorials.com/images/user-profile.png);
 }
```